# how to assign data to include layout in xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout, include

Assume we have a layout contains a TextView:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    style="@style/text_style"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then include this layout several times:

```
<include android:id="@+id/info1" layout="@layout/myLayout" />
<include android:id="@+id/info2" layout="@layout/myLayout" />
<include android:id="@+id/info3" layout="@layout/myLayout" />
```

Is it possible to assign text into each TextView in the xml file which contains these layouts?
If not, then how to assign in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, For this you need to identify you layout

```
LinearLayout info1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.info1);
```

Then with this layout object you need to identify you TextView

```
TextView text1 = (TextView)info1.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text1.setText("Your text");
```